# Play Store Build vs Unity Build - Compatibility Issues

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I have made an app that uses AR Core in unity, minimum API is 24 and target API is 32,my device has API 29, the APK build works when installed via a USB but play store build (AAB) says version is incompatible with device. Why and how to fix it? Nothing extra is added to the app.

I tried to manually install sdk 29 and set that path to Unity but it clashed with jdk 11